# Why does call does not work as A sort function?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm reading [javascript the good parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do), and the author gives an example that goes like so:

```
['d','c','b','a'].sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

Which behaves as expected.
Now I have tried to do something like this - which is the next logical step:

```
['d','c','b','a'].sort(String.prototype.localeCompare.call);
```

And that fails with an error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Now I left wondering why...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`call` needs to be bound to `localeCompare`:

```
['d','c','b','a'].sort(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.localeCompare));
```

The reason you are having a problem is that you are passing `sort` `Function.prototype.call`. As you may know, when no `this` is otherwise provided, it will be the global object (`window` in browser environments). Thus, when `sort` tries to call the function passed to it, it will be calling `call` with `this` set to the global object, which in most (all?) cases is not a function. Therefore, you must bind `call` so `this` is always `localeCompare`.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: That's what it's supposed to do. You don't use `localeCompare` like `"some string".localeCompare("a", "b")`; you use it like `"a".localeCompare("b")`.

Comment: Hi! thanks, I found the solution also and got the idea, but whoosh that was fast :)
on a side note i think this place needs more questions that are just for the share interest of the language...

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a reference to the `call` function without retaining any relationship to the `localeCompare` method you intend it to be called upon. So `sort` will invoke the function referenced by`String.prototype.localeCompare.call`, but it will invoke it in the global context, not as the method of some function object.

As @icktoofay pointed out, you need to bind the `call` function to `localeCompare`. Here's a much oversimplified demonstration of how this is done without the `bind` method:

```
function simpleBind(fn, _this) {
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(_this, arguments);
    }
}

['d','c','b','a'].sort(simpleBind(Function.prototype.call, 
                                  String.prototype.localeCompare));
```

Comment: thanks, nice bind function. ;) Take a look here, i really like what is done here: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that `String.prototype.localeCompare.call` returns a reference to `Function.prototype.call` not to `String.prototype.localeCompare` as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it! 
this does the trick:

```
['d','x','z','a'].sort(String.prototype.localeCompare.call.bind(String.prototype.localeCompare))
```

Cause when you think about it the sort function actually calls apply on call so it needs to be bound to the string object in order to execute in scope. 
^_^